# double url apache htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, double, url-rewriting

I have been searching the world wide web for a while now but can't seem to solve the issue.

I have a site where the base url has been entered as:

http://mydomain.com

The CMS will then a '/' at the end. Now, when the RSS feed is created the url does this:

http://mydomain.com/http://mydomain.com/link/to/page/location.htm

I haveonly just really started to look into regular expression with the .htaccess file and can't seem to figure this out?

Has anyone had this problem or can somebody point me in the right direction?

The page created for the link is a 404.

Cheers

smilinmonki666

Comment: some tips: remove signature and cheers from the question, tell us more about 'the cms', show your current apache rewrites,  check the settings of this cms

Comment: Sorry. Just joined.

Using Contao for the CMS and have a good few articles created already. will get a copy of the .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I'm using Zend Framework and when I was initializing the front controller options, I was setting baseUrl to **www.mydomain.com** which made every link to be like this **www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com**.

I've left baseUrl to "" and it works perfectly. I hope this answer will help others with a similar problem.